# MongoDB Insert unique email only condition is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my mongoose schema, i have the below two fields

```
username: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "user name required"],
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "email required"],
      trim: true,
      unqiue: true,
    }
```

My username field is inserted only if it is unique. But email field is not getting restricted for duplicate values.

Please suggest me a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You misspelled `unique`

Comment: Hi @robertklep , I have now editted my schema and started the server again. But still duplicate error is not coming. Insertion is successful.

Comment: That's probably because the collection underlying the model already exists in the database, and Mongoose doesn't recreate it (and, hence, also doesn't create a unique index for it). You may have to add the unique index manually, or run [`Model.ensureIndexes()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes) (consider that up to now, you have allowed duplicates to be inserted, which means that  adding a unique index may cause errors without fixing the duplicates or starting with a clean collection).

Comment: Sir, I have dropped the collection . and tested insertion newly. This time .. even the username duplicate error is not occuring . Why? All duplications are allowed

Comment: Please post that as a new question, preferably with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sir @robertklep , I have created a new thread here with minimal coding as u said. Kindly help me. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626644/mongodb-alter-the-unique-of-my-schema-not-reflecting-during-my-new-insertions