# MongoDB - altering the unique property of my field in schema - is not reflecting during my new insertions

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have my MongoDb database named School.
I have "user" collection.

The below is my Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "first name required"],
    trim: true,
    text: true,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "last name required"],
    trim: true,
    text: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "user name required"],
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email required"],
    trim: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "first name required"],
    trim: true,
    text: true,
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

In the above schema, email, username are unique.

But even though I pass duplicate values, the insertions are successful.

**MY controller.js**

```
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const { validateEmail, validateLength } = require("../helpers/validation");
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      username,
      password,
      bYear,
      bDay,
      bMonth,
      gender,
    } = req.body;

    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: "Email is invalid",
      });
    }
    if (!validateLength(first_name, 3, 30)) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message:
          "First Name - Format Mismatch- Min length - 3 , Max Length - 30",
      });
    }
    

    const cryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

    console.log("crypted =" + cryptedPassword);

    const user = await new User({
      first_name,
      last_name,
      email,
      username,
      password : cryptedPassword,
      bYear,
      bDay,
      bMonth,
      gender,
    }).save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I have deleted my 'User' collection and again tried to run the 'post' request from Postman. But still, duplicates are getting inserted.

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set your index by declaring on the schema with the `index` function:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'first name required'],
    trim: true,
    text: true,
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'last name required'],
    trim: true,
    text: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'user name required'],
    trim: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'email required'],
    trim: true,
    unique: false,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'first name required'],
    trim: true,
    text: true,
  },
});

// Define your index
userSchema.index({ username: 1, email: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: It worked perfect. But it seems it will cause significant performance impact. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-creation/#index-build-impact-on-database-performance